# Importing Wally into Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to import [Wally](https://github.com/Musenkishi/wally) into Android studio and I am confused as to what I have to do.

It states in the Github page that I need to specify my release- and debug keystore files into the local properties file in the root of the project.

I have imported it into my Android studio using the gradle file and everything appears fine.

I can see the local.properties file and when I open it it displays this:

[image]

Where do I specify my debug in this file like it states on the Github page?

I am new to Android studio, sorry if this is a stupid question, but I am confused as to where I need to specify my files like it says I need to on the Github page for the project to compile.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Here's what I have so far:

[image]

Inside local.properties I have:

```
keystore.props.file=../../keystore.properties
```

Inside the local.propeties I have:

```
store=../../AlphaKeystore.jks
alias=alpha
pass=mypass
storePass=mypass
```

And then I am getting the following errors in the build.gradle:

[image]

Have I done anything wrong? thanks.

**EDIT 2**

Here's what I get in the log and I am still getting the same errors in the build.gradle after making amendments:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug key is not stored in the local.properties, you just need to put it in the root folder (The author apparently made a typo...). The local.properties inside the project is not used for anything other than the path to the Android SDK. You need to make another one outside the project folder. Below you will see where you should put the files.

[image: Notice that the local.properties is located outside the project]

The highlighted local.properties contains:

```
keystore.props.file=../../keystore.properties
```

keystore.properties should contain the release alias, password, and store password:

```
store=../../keystore.jks
alias=your_alias
pass=your_password
storePass=your_store_password
```

Note that these .properties files are just plain text-files so there's no trick making them.

Comment: Try replacing 

`keyProps.load(new FileInputStream(file(localProps['keystore.properties'])))`

with

`keyProps.load(new FileInputStream(file(localProps['keystore.props.file'])))`

Hopefully that fixes your problem :)

Comment: hmm I am still getting the same error, I've updated my question with a new screenshot.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Your OS (Windows) is hiding the actual file extension for `local.properties` and `keystore.properties`. Either change this setting in Windows (as described [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7)) or change the reference to `local.properties.txt` and `keystore.properties.txt` inside the build.gradle file.

Comment: I've added the .txt extension to the names, and now I am getting Error:(73, 0) Neither path nor baseDir may be null or empty string. path='null' basedir='G:\App development\wally\wally-master\wally' in my logcat, I've also un checked "Hide extensions for known file types" in my windows.

Comment: Also, this is the line where the problem occurs http://i.gyazo.com/46cb644b3bed2285fb24b5d9b6ed4e67.png

Comment: I also get stuck with this problem. Could you help us?@Musenkishi . And have you solved the problem? @Jack ?